A (not so) K₁₂ problem
The following map on the torus was devised by Peter Ungar and John Leech.

It has 7 mutually adjacent faces  each homeomorphic to a disk. In addition, geometrically the whole map is face-transitive – any face can be brought to any other face by a symmetry of the map.
Can you find a map on the six-holed torus with 12 faces and all the above-listed properties (mutual adjacency, faces homeomorphic to a disk, geometric face-transitivity)?


 What face-transitive solids have a rotation group of order 12, and 6 edges that are invariant under the group?


Do you have a solution in mind? I feel already embedding a six-holed torus in 3-d such that one can cut it into 12 face-transitiy pieces seems non-trivial.

@quarague Yes, I drew up a solution prior to writing this question.

Here it is:

 

Explanation...
What is that?



 It is a cube!




 Each face is divided in two rectangular 2x1 regions with the same area.




 Each edge should touch the long side of an area in one face and the short sides of the areas in the other face.




 Drill a (worm)hole in the center of each edge exiting in the opposite edge.



Which properties it have?



 Opposite regions are painted in opposite colors: Black vs White; Red vs Cyan; Blue vs Yellow; Green vs Magenta; Orange vs Skyblue; Petroleum-dark-cyanish vs Pink.




 Each hole entrance is centered in the intersection of three mutually adjacent regions.




 Since a cube have 12 edges and each tunnel have an entrance and exit on some edge, then there are 6 tunnels.




 The tunnels are labeled as A to F. Since each tunnel has one entrance and one exit, we give numbers 1 and 2 for that. But since they have no preferential direction, it is indifferent to say that 1 is entrance and 2 is exit or vice-versa.




 The internal surface of the tunnels should be painted as continuations of the regions on the outer surface.




 All the regions have the same size and shape. This weren't a requirement, but is beautiful.



Details about topology



 Topologically, a cube is equivalent to a sphere. So I created a cube and drilled 6 holes there (12 if you count entrance and exit as different holes). Any other simply-connected 3-dimensional shape without holes or handles will do (we drill the holes later). However cubes have some properties that makes this easier.




 You could also use handles instead of tunnels. The only differences are that with handles, you should paint the external surface while with tunnels you should paint the internal one. And also that tunnels are drilled while handles are glued there. But for now on, I will refer only to holes and tunnels, but all of that is equally valid for handles instead. If you are going to construct that object in real life or 3D-render it, maybe the task is much easier with handles.




 Make the holes be curved tunnels in order to avoiding them intersecting each other (or use handles).




 It doesn't matter if the tunnels are very long or if they are effectivelly 0-length. Nor if they are straight down or as curled and twisted as a bowl of spaguetti. Topologically, it is the same thing.




 Also, it doesn't matter if the regions coming out of a hole spreads out a few meters in the plains around it. This is specially handy for seeing what is going on in 0-length tunnels.




 If there are 6 tunnels, topologically it is a torus with 6 holes.



Why are the holes' neighbourhoods so complicated?
A naive attempt to join many regions inside a hole would be like this (tunnel A):

 

But blue and yellow won't touch each other. So, the solution is to do this:

 

But with that solution, magenta won't touch green nor cyan won't touch red. Won't this make it wrong?

 No, because in this hole, blue and yellow are the large sides and they meet each other and every other color. This means that magenta will meet green in some other hole (tunnel F). Also, in some other third hole, red and cyan will meet (tunnel E).

 The only place where two opposite colors meet is in the tunnel connecting them from their large side. If two opposite colors enters a tunnel and don't meet each other, that is because that tunnel was in their smaller side, not in their large side.

Hole orientation
Let's see Alice and Bob passing some cables on a hole in a block...

 

So what?

 Note that the orientation of the cables in one end of the hole is the mirror reflection of the orientation in the other end. The orientation of things traversing holes in topological surfaces is something important to pay attention. Otherwise, we could mess up the solution of the puzzle. The two different entrances of each tunnel are mirror images of each other.

But I see 19 hole entrances, not 12!

 I repeated those holes that shows up in edges that have been cut in two disjoint parts when opening the cube. I only made this for clarity and for making it easy to match different tunnel orientations.

Why some labels are facing sideways or upside down?

 To match their orientation. They have the region with the broad side down and the other two regions up. This is also important when observing a hole that shows up more than once.

Possible future work



 It is possible to make the borders around the holes less jagged, since only the broad sides need some jaggedness there. It is also possible to completely eliminate the jaggedness by making the regions from each side of the tunnel to spiral in opposite directions in order to make them don't meet face-on inside the tunnel. Also, twisting the tunnel itself making it spiraling is also possible in order to eliminate the jaggedness.




 Of course, instead of a cube, you could just use any random irregular piece of rock with twelve hole entrances tunnelling it in six tunnels, but then the regions wouldn't have the same size and shape and that wouldn't be "elegant". So, I conjecture that there should exist elegant solutions for every platonic solid: Two regions and two hole entrances per edge in tetrahedrons; Two hole entrances and two regions per vertex for octahedrons; One hole entrance and one region per face in dodecahedrons; One hole entrance and one region per vertex in icosahedrons. For a ball, it is also possible: just paint and drill it as if it was a platonic solid. What types of other shapes allow elegant solutions is an open problem.




This is an excellent answer. If I could, I'd give it an extra upvote just for Petroleum-dark-cyanish!

Great work! Beautiful! Need a 3d visualization of this. Nit: the 6 wormholes can't be straight lines or they would meet in the middle. But you can't perturb them without losing symmetry. Indeed each wormhole must pass through the centre or you can't rotate the cube by 180 degrees.

@Laska I stated that the holes would be curved for this very reason. But there is also another obvious (and in pactical terms easier) solution: Using handles instead of tunnels (I edited the answer to account for that also).

I agree handles would be more practical. Sorry, my real question was whether non-straight lines can be chosen to keep the beautiful symmetry. The rotational symmetries are unaffected by R -> 1/R transformation, so this is not about handles vs wormholes.

This is the solution I drew before posting this question as proof that there is a solution in the first place.

 It was also uploaded to Wikimedia Commons.

 The map is drawn on a tetrahedron whose faces are divided into three equal parts (i.e. a degenerate triakis tetrahedron). "Arrows" pointing at each other are attachment points for the same handle; there are six pairs of "arrows" corresponding to the tetrahedron's edges, so six handles as required.

A 3D rendering:

 

Why did I go straight to 12 rather than pose the same question at (say) 8 regions?

 Consider the dual formulation: embed a complete graph $K_n$ on an orientable surface of minimum genus. Euler's formula gives a lower bound on that minimum genus of
 $$\left\lceil\frac{(n-3)(n-4)}{12}\right\rceil$$
 and the Ringel–Youngs theorem says this bound can be achieved.
 Dualising this embedding gives a map of pairwise mutually adjacent regions. But this can be face-transitive only if the primal graph embedding is a triangulation iff the division in the genus lower bound is exact iff $n$ is 0, 3, 4 or 7 mod 12.


Again beautiful. It's amazing that one solution is based in the cube, while the other is based on tetrahedron
